# Alter MBR order of partitions after copying partitions to larger drive

Tags: mbr, cloning

I have a new 1TB laptop drive that I want to clone an existing drive to.  The issue is that I want to reorder and resize the existing partitions.

The existing partition table for the drive is

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    24578047    12288000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  11GB (former recovery partition of a Windows drive)
/dev/sda2   *    24578048   216989695    96205824    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  92GB Windows install partition
/dev/sda3       216989955   863465471   323237758+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  308GB Windows/Linux universal storage
/dev/sda4       863467518   976771071    56651777    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       863467520   976771071    56651776   83  Linux            55GB Ubuntu Partition
```

I want to change the ordering to

```
2 x 110 GB for both Windows and Linux
1 x  25 GB for web server and development
1 x 684 GB for Windows/Linux universal storage.
```

I can create these partitions and copy the corresponding partion over using

```
dd if=/dev/sdaX of=/dev/sdbX bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

but that leaves the MBR untouched.  If I copy over the existing MBR, it will be invalid since the order of partitions is very different on the new drive.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted.  Create an empty partition table on the new disk, and copy/paste the partitions over.

Comment: And then?  If I boot from the drive, will GRUB pop up?

Comment: Could you be more verbose?

Comment: @Jason, no, you will need to install grub to the MBR.